# Anime about a boy and a corrupt village

Tags: story-identification, anime

The anime I'm searching for is about a guy who leaves his village with 2 friends - another guy and a girl. They get separated and he searches for them. After a while the guy ends up in a town without money and decides to sleep on the street. A young lady drives by in a carriage and offers him to stay with her family in their mansion.

The whole family seems pretty nice at first. While staying with them the mansion gets attacked by a group of people trying to kill the family. The guy protects them. During the fight the girl of the family runs to some kind of shack. Inside the shack are the 2 missing friends of the guy. They've been tortured. It turns out the family captures and tortures people they think are worthless and the group attacking them are the good ones.

The guy confronts the girl about why she did it and she said they were worthless and it was her right to kill them. She also said that the female friend of the guy had more beautiful hair than her and that she couldn't allow her to live; that she had to be punished. They kill the evil girl and the guy joins the group in their quest to change the situation in the town.

**What is the name of this anime story?**

Comment: What about this anime was science-fictional or fantastical?

Answer (score 10):

What you're describing is the plot of the first episode from the anime [Akame ga Kill!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akame_ga_Kill!).

The protagonist is *Tatsumi* who at first fights the assassins attacking the family he stays at but after learning the shocking truth about them, turns against them instead. He is afterwards taken and eventually recruited into the group of assassins. The assassins are known as *Night Raid* and are actually rebels.

*Akame* (which means red-eye) is actually the name of the main heroine who is a master swordsman and has blood red eyes.

Comment: Shame the OP never checked back because he is **definitely** describing the first episode of *Akame ga Kill*.